# Error while exporting from a DataGridView into an Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, datagridview

I collect some data into a `DataGridView` "dataGridView2"and I want to export it to a worksheet in an excel but I got an `HRESULT` error with error code `0x800A03EC`, following is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@path);
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

    //Couunt the number cells in the
    //datagridview asign it to an integers
    //variable
    int rHtcount = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
    int iii = 0;

    //put each values from each cells of the
    //datagridview into each cell in the
    //destination
    for(; iii < rHtcount; iii++)
    {
         worksheet.Cells[iii + 2, "H"].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[iii].Cells[0].Value;
    }

    app.Visible = true;
    workbook.Close();
}
```

Please help what else can I do because I think the code above is correct and I don't why it brings out such an error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `new.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();` 
with `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();`

HTH!!!